# Work done by compressor to fill a tank

Tags: thermodynamics, compressors

A reciprocating air compressor is used to fill rapidly a $3m^3$ tank at $30°c$ and $1\ bar$. The filing process is governed by $pv^{1.4}=constant$. The effects of kinetic energy may be neglected. The ratio of the final to initial mass of air in the tank is 4.

What is the work input to the compressor?

I am struck up with the problem. Please help me with how to solve this question.

Thanks

Attempted solution by OP(link in comments):
[image: attempted solution in comments by OP to question]

Comment: So have a hint: work out how many kg of gas initially and then finally.

Comment: Hey, Mike thank you. I have tried the question and have a solution. Can you please tell me if I am correct? https://imgur.com/a/HI0J0T3